# Como Hacer una consulta parecida a LIKE de SQL pero con un String en Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, string

Hola a todos actualmente he desarrollado un sistemas de ventas en Java y MYSQL, normalmente el sistema estuvo funcionando de manera local; pero por necesidades del negocio he subido la BD a un servidor. El problema es que anteriormente para buscar un producto se ejecutaba por cada tecla que se introducía una consulta SQL con like:

```
String filtro= "%"+texto+"%";
        String sql = "SELECT Codigo, Nombre, Ubicacion, Costo, Precio, Stock FROM productos WHERE Codigo LIKE"+'"'+filtro+'"';
```

Pero al subir la BD a un servidor la consulta ya no es buena ya que tiene que hacer peticiones al servidor por cada pulsación de tecla que se de; lo cual hace que sea muy lento.
Por esa razón he creado un método que se ejecuta al abrir el formulario, y almacena de manera local en un Tlista todo el inventario de productos; para que de esta manera ya no se este haciendo consultas al servidor a cada momento.
Pero mi problema es como hago para hacer una consulta tipo like con la cadena del nombre del producto almacenado en la lista.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Esta es la consulta que quiero hacer a la lista:

```
        String codigo = null;
        String nombre = null;
        String precio = null;
        TLista data=listaProductos.obtenerDatos();
        for(int j=0; j<data.Cantidad(); j++){
        Producto obj= (Producto) data.Obtener(j);
        if(obj.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(busqueda))  //aca es donde quiero hacer la comparacion tipo LIKE
       {
        codigo=obj.getCodigo();
        nombre=obj.getNombre();
        precio=String.valueOf(obj.getPrecioVentaReferencial());
        }
       }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El equivalente es utilizar expresiones regulares. En una expresión regular`.*` significa cualquier cosa, por lo que: `.*hola.*` es lo mismo que `LIKE '%hola%'`

```java
class Demo306880 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You", "Hell", "Gello");

        List<String> matches = getMatchingStrings(items, ".*ell.*");

        for (String match: matches) {
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getMatchingStrings(List<String> list, String regex) {
      ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    
      for (String item: list) {
        if (pattern.matcher(item).matches()) {
          matches.add(item);
        }
      }
    
      return matches;
    }
}
```

Dicho esto, es posible que si la lista de productos es demasiado larga este sistema se vuelva muy lento. En general lo que yo intentaría es no enviar la búsqueda tras cada pulsación sino cuando el usuario ha dejado de escribir durante cierto tiempo.

La regla podría ser algo como: "Se han escrito al menos 2-3 carácteres y hace 0.3-0.5 segundos que no se escribe.

De todas formas es cuestión de valorar. Ya que cargar la lista en memoria también tiene la ventaja de no ir por la red a pedir datos a la DB.